# Creating an ArrayList from a JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

So I have a JSON just like the picture below stored as `MYJSON`--

[image]

My plan is to retrieve all the object from `childObject0` and store them in an `ArrayList` so they can be processed later. So I did-

```
ArrayList<String> childLists = new ArrayList<String>();
 try {
       JSONArray childArray = MYJSON.getJSONArray("childObject0");
       for (int i = 0; i<jArray.length(); i++
                 ) {
           //I lost it here! How can I append to `childList` from `childArray`?
                
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can't figure out how to append. Is this right approach? `childObject0` is dynamic and the count changes time to time.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each object in `childObject0` is json, you can store it as an `ArrayList<JSONObject>`. That should make the objects easier to process than as Strings.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> childList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
try {
    JSONArray childArray = MYJSON.getJSONArray("childObject0");
    for (int i = 0; i < childArray.length(); i++) {
        childList.add(childArray.getJSONObject(i));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use of `ArrayList<JSONObject>` saved the day!